# Finding Row And Column Location Of Component In GridBagLayout

Tags: java, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I am a high school student making a flashcards program where users can store sets and words which are written to a text file. These sets are displayed on a home screen in a grid bag layout.

[image]

The set names, subject and number of cards are labels, while Add Words, Play and Delete Set are buttons.

When a user clicks on any of the buttons they should be able to interact with the chosen set. **The buttons all work, but the problem that I am running into is that the program has no way of telling which button belongs to which set.**

If there was some way that I could find the column of the button which is clicked, I can correspond that with the text file with the set names on it.

Buttons are all copies of each other, and are not stored in an array.

My button action listners:

```
btnAddWords.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p) {     
   frmWords s = new frmWords(deckName, newXPoint, newYPoint);
   s.setVisible(true);      
   }
 });
```

My button declarations:

```
        JButton btnAddWords = new JButton("Add Words"); 
        btnAddWords.setOpaque(false);
        btnAddWords.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnAddWords.setBorder(null);
        btnAddWords.setBorderPainted(false);

        JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
        btnPlay.setOpaque(false);
        btnPlay.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnPlay.setBorder(null);
        btnPlay.setBorderPainted(false);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete Set");
        btnDelete.setOpaque(false);
        btnDelete.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnDelete.setBorder(null);
        btnDelete.setBorderPainted(false);
```

This is my Grid Bag set up:

```
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(lblDeckName[i],gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("      "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx =2;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel (subject),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("                   "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel(strLineNumber2),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("             |  "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(btnAddWords,gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 7;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("  |  "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 8;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(layoutBackground.add(btnPlay),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 9;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("  |  "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 10;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(btnDelete,gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 11;
        gbc.gridy = i;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("  |"),gbc);
```

If there is a better way to do this I would love to learn how to do that, otherwise if you could point me in the right direction, that would be amazing!!!

Thanks heaps!!!! :)

Comment: You should include the information in your action listener. No need to check where it is in the layout.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please. I don't quite understand 

Comment: How do *you* know which buttons belong to which set? You can just put that into your action listener when you create it. I would try to post an answer that shows this, but I don't see how you are determining what a "set" is.